# Export a class import an object

Tags: javascript

Here is my code (vanillaJS):

```
// app.js
import Block from './models/index';
console.log(typeof(Block));
let block = new Block();

// /models/block.js
export default class Block {
    constructor() {
    }
};

// /models/index.js
import Block from './block';
export default { 
    Block
};
```

The console.log in app.js tell me that Block is an object.

I want to import Block as a class not an object.

What did I do wrong?
Is it possible?

Good day.

Comment: There's no such thing as a type "class" to begin with. At most you get `"function"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already explained, `{ Block }` - the thing you exported - is an object indeed. However, I would recommend not to default-export anything from `models/index.js` as the solution.
I think you were looking for named exports here:

```
// /models/index.js
import Block from './block';
export { // <- this is not an object literal
    Block // short for: `Block as Block`
};
// or in one line:
export { default as Block } from './block';
```

```
// app.js
import { Block } from './models/index';
//     ^       ^
console.log(typeof(Block));
let block = new Block();
```

Comment: indeed, I was looking for named exports

Answer (score 2):

Here

```
// /models/index.js
import Block from './block';
export default { 
    Block
};
```

you indeed export an object (with property `Block`). To export class just do:

```
// /models/index.js
import Block from './block';
export default Block

// or in one line: export { default } from './block'
```